# Mdi form in winform c# using sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, mdichild

```
frmCustomerDetails cd;
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        this.Hide();
        frmDairyManagementSystem cda = new frmDairyManagementSystem();
        //cd.Show();

        if (cd == null || cd.IsDisposed)
        {


            cd = new frmCustomerDetails();
            cd.MdiParent = cda;
            cd.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            cd.Show();
        }
        else
            cd.Activate();
        //frmCustomerDetails frm = new frmCustomerDetails();
        //frm.Show();
        cd.txtCustomerID.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        cd.dateTimePicker1.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtCustomerName.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        cd.grpGender.Text = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtAddress.Text = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtPhone.Text = dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtEmail.Text = dr.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtMobileNo.Text = dr.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtNotes.Text = dr.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        cd.btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
        cd.btnDelete.Enabled = true;
        cd.btnSave.Enabled = false;
        cd.txtCustomerName.Focus();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the data in my mdi child form but the code does not work. It does not take any value to my mdi child form

Please help me how i can retrieve data to my mdi child form

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data needed by the child form to frmCustomerDetails constructor -- in this case you should define custom constructor in frmCustomerDetails class.
Or, you can create custom Show method in the frmCustomerDetails class and pass the data in the method. Inside the frmCustomerDetails class, store the passed data in the private fields and/or bind the data to controls.

So, inside the frmCustomerDetails class it could look like this:

```
void Show(DataGridViewRow dr)
{
    //TODO: Store cell values from dr to private fields and/or bind them to controls
    this.MdiParent = cda;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.Show();
}
```